# Compare 2 different Arrays by ID and calculate difference

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got 2 arrays

**ArrayA** = `{"data":{"PlayerList":[{"Platform":1,"PlayerExternalId":205288,"Price":250,"RemainingTime":22},{"Platform":1,"PlayerExternalId":205753,"Price":10000,"RemainingTime":22}]}}`

**ArrayB** = `{"datafut": [{"currentPricePs4": "4149000","currentPriceXbox": "3328000","PlayerExternalId": "151152967"},{"currentPricePs4": "3315000","currentPriceXbox": "2720000","PlayerExternalId": "151198320"}]}`

ArrayB is like a small database to compare prices. ArrayA needs theoretically an [Interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript) with ArrayB. But this creates a new ArrayC which is complicated for me because I need the index of the results from ArrayA.

Moreover when comparing both array IDs, I need to compare both prices and calculate a difference into a variable so I can work with it later. How can I achieve this?

This is my pseudo code. Idk if this is even the right way..

```
Filter ArrayB by ArrayA //by playerID
for(
NewPrice = ArrayA.price / ArrayB.price + Index of ArrayA.price
index = Index of ArrayA.price)
```

Edit: or could I append the price from arrayB to arrayA and can calculate then somehow?

Comment: What exactly you need in a new array? playerId, pricefromArrayA, priceFromArrayBXbox, priceFromArrayBPS4? what do you mean by Index here?

Comment: I need platform ARRAYa playerexternalid, price, ARRAYb currentprice xbox and ps4. The new array.. If so.. Needs to have the ArrayA[0] playerid=1 at the same index so ArrayC[0] playerid =1

Comment: and players in arrayA will be unique?

Comment: Yes 100% unique ids

Comment: But that unique I'd may can be in ArrayA multiple times. But its in arrayB only once*

Comment: Please check my answer now, i updated and hopefully it will work as expected.

Comment: Wow wow wow apparently I can't test atm. Will do ASAP (May tomorrow) and will reply / vote. Thanks until now!amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass both arrays to following function: I have stored index, now if you only need index, you don't need to sort it otherwise I am sorting it on the base of index to keep the original order.

```
function mergeArrays(arrayA, arrayB) {

    var players = arrayA.data.PlayerList;
    var data = arrayB.data;
    var arrayC = [];

    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {  
        var playerId = data[i].PlayerExternalId;
        for(let j=0; j<players.length; j++) {
            if(players[j].PlayerExternalId != playerId) {
                continue;
            }
            var obj = {};
            obj.playerId = playerId;
            obj.index = j;
            obj.price = players[j].price;
            obj.xboxprice = data[i].currentPriceXbox;
            obj.ps4price = data[i].currentPricePs4;
            arrayC.push(obj);
        }
    }
    arrayC.sort((a,b) => (a.index < b.index)?-1:(a.index>b.index?1:0));
    return arrayC;
}
```